# What to use in Angular instead of setTimeout for certain changes?

Tags: angular

Sometimes changes are not reflected in Angular unless the code is wrapped in a "setTimeout" method. Im wondering, is there a "cleaner" or "more Angular" way to achieve the same functionality?

The situation I am referring to is when I have a `ViewChild` with content being projected into it but I can't "see" what's in that view child unless I try to do so within a setTimeout method within `AfterContentInit`

```
    ngAfterContentInit(): void {
        setTimeout(() => {

            // This logs "undefined" if not wrapped in 
            // a setTimeout
            console.log(this.projectedContent);
        })
    }
```

Comment: It's quite normal that you can't see things in the DOM before the DOM is built. The right question you should be asking is, why are you trying to react to changes in the DOM. When it should be the DOM that reacts to changes in the component, not the other way around. It is unclear from your question what you are trying to do, but I would think that whatever is creating a change in your DOM can be observed in the script file of your component, instead of on the DOM itself. If you are trying to observe user inputs you should use any of the events you can bind to (keyup, click, ...).

Comment: Have you tried `ngAfterViewInit` instead? Also, `queueMicrotask` accomplishes a similar thing to `setTimeout`, but the callback is not pushed all the way to the back of the queue. There's nothing wrong with using these two functions to change the order of operations.

Comment: @H3AR7B3A7 To further elaborate, I have a navbar component and needed to be able to add dropdowns with unknown content to unknown top-level links in the navbar. I did this by adding the dropdown in the `ng-content` part of the navbar and then "manually" move the content for each dropdown to the link in question in the navbar using `Renderer2`. The issue I was having is that unless I called "setTimeout" on the function holding the `Renderer2` methods, the projected content wouldn't be moved where I wanted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [ChangeDetectorRef](https://angular.io/api/core/ChangeDetectorRef)

A little example: focus a input under a *ngIf

```
  <button (click)="focus()">focus</button>

  <input #myinput *ngIf="toogle" />
  @ViewChild('myinput') el: ElementRef;
  constructor(private cdr: ChangeDetectorRef) {}

  focus() {
    if (!this.toogle) {
      this.toogle = true;
      this.cdr.detectChanges();
      this.el.nativeElement.focus();
    } else this.toogle = false;
  }
```

Another way is using a decorator like [NetBasal](https://netbasal.com/create-and-test-decorators-in-javascript-85e8d5cf879c)

```
function timeout(milliseconds: number = 0) {
  return function (
    target: any,
    propertyKey: string,
    descriptor: PropertyDescriptor
  ) {
    const originalMethod = descriptor.value;

    descriptor.value = function () {
      setTimeout(() => {
        originalMethod.apply(this, arguments);
      }, milliseconds);
    };

    return descriptor;
  };
}

//use:
  focus() {
    if (!this.toogle) {
      this.toogle = true;
      this.setFocus();
    } else this.toogle = false;
  }

  @timeout()
  setFocus() {
    this.el.nativeElement.focus();
  }
```

See [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-g8zfww?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)